# Returns from Recursive methods

Tags: java

I am trying to practice understanding recursion but the following program has me stumped. How is the answer being returned as 14? Can someone show me how this is calculating? I tried to put in  afew print statments to help me identify what is going on but I do not see how spot is decremented after it goes up to 4. I have the program and output to console below, please help.

from console:

```
The spot 1 is 0
The spot 1 is 1
The spot 1 is 2
The spot 1 is 3
The spot 1 is 4
when spot = length. the spot is 4
 The value is 4
spot after return 3
 the spot 2 is 3
 The value is 8
spot after return 2
 the spot 2 is 2
 The value is 11
spot after return 1
 the spot 2 is 1
 The value is 13
spot after return 0
 the spot 2 is 0
The answer is 14
```

Code:

```
public class Recurs1 {
    public static void main (String [] arg) {
        Recurs1 r = new Recurs1();
        r.compute();
    }

    public void compute() {
        int [] stuff = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int answer = go(stuff, 0);
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);  
    }

    private int go(int[] numbers, int spot) {
        System.out.println("The spot 1 is " + spot);
      //System.out.println("0 is " + numbers[0] + " 1 is " + numbers[1] + " 2 is "  + numbers[2] + " 1 is " + numbers[3]);
        if (numbers.length == spot) {
            System.out.println("when spot = length. the spot is " + spot); return spot;     
            }
        int value = go(numbers, spot + 1 ); 
        System.out.println(" The value is " + value); 
        System.out.println("spot after return " + spot);
        System.out.println(" the spot 2 is " + spot);
        return value + numbers[spot]; 
     }

}
```

Comment: What is your function supposed to calculate?

Comment: The problem gives you the sum of the values plus the number of values.  You haven't said whether this is what you wanted or not, so I would have to say it works this way just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try returning 0 instead of spot when you've reached the end. You're tacking 4 (the current value of spot) onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to write a method which is summing the array, then the problem is that on the line of go() where you have if(numbers.length == spot) you are returning spot, which is 4, and it is adding that to the total value (because the method that called go(numbers, 4) is setting value to that and adding it.)  Instead, you should be returning 0 to stop recursion (because the result will be 1+2+3+4+0)

Try this on for size:

```
private int go(int[] numbers, int spot){
    if(numbers.length == spot) return 0;
    return go(numbers, spot+1) + numbers[spot];
}
```

Comment: I am just trying to determine what this exact code is doing durring runtime and how the values are beimg calculated. Can you walk me through the code i posted and show me what it is doing? Thanks,

Comment: Can somone please help me identify what this code is doing. I doin't wnat to change anything in the code. I want to understand what how this specific program is getting its vales. Thanks.

Comment: Think of each method call as a value.  So, where it says `go(numbers, 0)` -- that's actually a number.  What number is it?  Well, then that's `go(numbers, 1) + 1`.  Well, what is `go(numbers,1)`?  It's `go(numbers, 2) + 2`.  So, our value of `go(numbers,0) = go(numbers,2) + 2 + 1`. `go(numbers,0) = go(numbers,3)+3+2+1`.  `go(numbers,0) = go(numbers,4)+4+3+2+1`.  And finally, `go(numbers,4) = 0` because `numbers.length == spot` and so `go(numbers,0) = 0+4+3+2+1`. = 10.

Comment: change the above comment for `go(numbers,4)` to be 4 for your original code (where you're calling `return spot` when `spot == 4`) and you'll get `go(numbers,0) = 4+4+3+2+1` = 14.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help walk you through it. Your program works it's way up until it calls go(numbers, 3+1), which returns 4, because numbers has 4 elements and spot is of value 4 (3+1).

At this point you are looking at a call stack of something like this:

```
answer = go(stuff, 0);
    value = go(numbers, 0 + 1);
        value = go(numbers, 1 + 1);
            value = go(numbers, 2 + 1);
                value = go(numbers, 3 + 1) = 4
```

Now it will work it's way back up the stack.

```
go(numbers, 2 + 1 );
```

Calling this will give you value+numbers[3], which is 4 + 4, with value coming from go(numbers, 3 + 1).

Next we have

```
go(numbers, 1 + 1 );
```

This will return go(numbers, 2 + 1 ) + numbers[2], which is 8 + 3 (or 11).

And then go(numbers, 0 + 1 ) is called, which returns go(numbers, 1 + 1 ) + numbers[1], which is 11 + 2 or 13.

Lastly, go(stuff, 0) can be calculated. This returns go(numbers, 0 + 1 ) + numbers[0], which is 13+1, or 14 - the answer you are currently getting.

I'm not sure if I actually explained much, but hopefully walking through it can show where your confusion is.

Another way of visualizing it would be something like this:

```
answer = go(stuff, 0);
    go(stuff, 0) = go(numbers, 0 + 1) + 1;
        go(numbers, 0 + 1) = go(numbers, 1 + 1) + 2;
            go(numbers, 1 + 1) = go(numbers, 2 + 1) + 3;
                go(numbers, 2 + 1) = go(numbers, 3 + 1) + 4;
                    go(numbers, 3 + 1) = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That is exactly what i needed to understand this.